# Linking Javascript file to html document for lab

Tags: java, html, css

I created a sample HTML file on my windows. I also have a script file in java.js file. I tried to link the file to html using  tag. Still it doesn't display according to the JavaScript. The html doesn't get manipulated using java file. Am i missing something. here is what i have

The Java script file is in that location mentioned in the src file
i am a beginner on this

Comment: Javascript is not Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that JavaScript and Java are two different Programming languages.
The rest below =>

```js
alert("Now JavaScript is hooked and Working");
console.log("You can find JavaScript in console of Your browser");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Html & JavaScript</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a
      target="_blank"
      href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript"
      >JavaScript. Read More</a
    >
    <h3>
      Please be Aware of that: <br />Java and JavaScript are two different
      programming languages!
    </h3>
    <a
      target="_blank"
      href="https://www.java.com/en/download/help/whatis_java.html"
      >Java. Read More</a
    >
  </body>
</html>
```

Create two files in the project directory on Your machine. For example, `index.html` and `script.js`. I have provided the code for each of them above.
Start the editor. For example VSCode with LiveServer in it and run `index.html`.
That's all.
Good luck  ;-)

Comment: THanks a lot Mario. I had a great learning on this. cheers

Comment: You're Welcome ;-) Best regards !